# how to access json data attribute

Tags: javascript, json, custom-data-attribute

I have a data-attribute for several element that I'm using to store an ID and a value for each picklist values for each element. These will all be used to populate one field in a modal if one of the elements is edited.

I've added the ID and name for each option for each element into the data attribute like so:

```
{id:a0Dd000000RT1dOEAT,name:aa},{id:a0Dd000000RT1dPEAT,name:bb},   {id:a0Dd000000RT1dQEAT,name:cc},{id:a0Dd000000RT1dREAT,name:dd},{id:a0Dd000000RT1dSEAT,name:ee}
```

These represents 5 picklist options for one of the elements.

What is the syntax to extract each one? I've tried versions of:

```
$('#elementID').data('picklistvalues')[0].id
```

and its not working, any suggestions? I'm obviously far from a javascript expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the value that `.data()` returns; *then* you can work with the value as a full JavaScript object.

```
var data = $('#elementID').data('picklistvalues');
// the attr value in the OP is not quite valid JSON
var obj = JSON.parse('[' + data + ']');
var id = obj[0].id;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you need to place quotes around the "id" values.  These are not quite numbers and will not likely parse as anything but strings.

Comment: Thanks, I added the quotes as suggested around all the attributes.